DB2 on CIS Amazon Linux 2023 Benchmark - Level 1
By following an tutorial blog of installing DB2 on Amazon Linux, after solving many dependencies error, in the end I'm facing an issue where I can't start the DB2.
Some troubleshooting steps I did on this CIS machine:
yum install libxcrypt-compat #From other posts to resolve dependencies error

cp /etc/os-release  /etc/lsb-release #From other posts


db2start: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

#Downgraded OpenSSL and manually moved the required libcrypto.so.1.1 to /lib64 directory from other resource, couldn't remember how I got it into the /usr/local/lib64

[root@ip-10-0-47-68 ec2-user]# ls /lib64/libcrypt*
/lib64/libcrypt.so        /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 # I manually moved here to bypass the error
/lib64/libcrypt.so.1      /lib64/libcrypto.so.3
/lib64/libcrypt.so.1.1.0  /lib64/libcrypto.so.3.0.5
/lib64/libcrypt.so.2      /lib64/libcryptsetup.so.12
/lib64/libcrypt.so.2.0.0  /lib64/libcryptsetup.so.12.9.0

The error I am facing now.
[db2inst1@ip-10-0-47-68 ~]$ db2start
SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004

Machine Information from /etc/os-release
[root@ip-10-0-47-68 ec2-user]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2023"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="2023"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:al2023"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2023.4.20240513"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2023"
HOME_URL="https://aws.amazon.com/linux/amazon-linux-2023/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023"
VENDOR_NAME="AWS"
VENDOR_URL="https://aws.amazon.com/"
SUPPORT_END="2028-03-15"

DB2 Diagnosis
[db2inst1@ip-10-0-47-68 ~]$ db2diag
2024-06-28-05.26.43.408034+000 I1E1858               LEVEL: Event
PID     : 25751                TID : 139661664188288 PROC : db2diag
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: ip-10-0-47-68.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, RAS/PD component, pdLogInternal, probe:120
START   : New Diagnostic Log file
DATA #1 : Build Level, 248 bytes
Instance "db2inst1" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11059"
with level identifier "060A010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.9.0", "s2310270807", "DYN2310270807AMD64", Fix Pack "0".
CPU: total:2 online:2 Cores per socket:2 Threading degree per core:1 SIMD:Y CPU Features:SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4,AVX2
CPU binding: not in use
CPU cache: L2:262144 bytes L3:47185920 bytes (shared by 2 threads)
Physical Memory(MB): total:3905 free:273
Virtual  Memory(MB): total:3905 free:273
Swap     Memory(MB): total:0 free:0
Kernel   Params: msgMaxMessageSize:8192 msgMsgMap:16384 msgMaxQueueIDs:32000
                 msgNumberOfHeaders:16384 msgMaxQueueSize:16384
                 msgMaxSegmentSize:16 shmMax:9223372036854775807 shmMin:1
                 shmIDs:4096 shmSegments:4096 semMap:1024000000 semIDs:32000
                 semNum:1024000000 semUndo:1024000000 semNumPerID:32000
                 semOps:500 semUndoSize:20 semMaxVal:32767
                 semAdjustOnExit:32767
Cur cpu time limit (seconds)  = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Cur file size limit (bytes) = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Cur data size (bytes)  = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Cur stack size (bytes)  = 0x0000000000800000
Cur core size (bytes)  = 0x0000000000000000
Cur memory size (bytes) = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
nofiles (descriptors)  = 0x000000000000FFFF
Cur maximum number of processes = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Disk: 4K Device Support: NONE

Information in this record is only valid at the time when this file was
created (see this record's time stamp)

2024-06-28-05.26.43.408833+000 I1860E439             LEVEL: Event
PID     : 25751                TID : 139661664188288 PROC : db2diag
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: ip-10-0-47-68.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, RAS/PD component, pdDiagArchiveDiagnosticLog, probe:88
CREATE  : DB2DIAG.LOG ARCHIVE : /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/db2diag.log_2024-06-28-05.26.43 : success
IMPACT  : Potential

db2diag invoked with the default set of filtering/formatting options
on file "/home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/db2diag.log".
Enter "db2diag -h" to get a short description of all available options.

I am new to DB2, any help or suggestions are appreciated, let me know if I need to upload anymore logs/outputs.
